# Elixir program, what does this program do?

Tags: object, process, elixir, spawn

this is one of the practice questions from the upcoming exam, and I have no idea what should be written for init() in order for the output to run.
If someone could help me out, that would be awsome

output: This is what I would run

```
p1=Pawn.new(),
Obj.call(p1,{:goto, 1, 2}),
1=Obj.call(p1, :x),
2=Obj.call(p1, :y),
Obj.call(p1,{:moveDelta , 3, 1}),
4=Obj.call(p1, :x ) ,
3=Obj.call(p1 ,:y ).
```

Add the necessary code to the following to support the API used above for the object pawn:

function: I need to fill out the init() function here.

```
defmodule Obj do

def call(obj,msg) do
send obj,{self(), msg}

receive do
Response -> Response
end
   end
      end

defmodule Pawn do
def new(), do: spawn(__MODULE__,:init, [] ).
def init() do: // fill this out
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Your question is all wrong. The first block looks more like erlang syntax. Your second block is not indented and is unreadable.

Comment: My professor sucks dude, but it is elixir I assure you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm reluctant to do all your homework for you. However, given that the code you were given is not valid Elixir, I'll provide you a partial solution. I've implemented the `:goto` and `:x` handlers. You should be able to figure out how to write the `:moveDelta` and `:y` handlers.

```
defmodule Obj do
  def call(obj, msg) do
    send obj, { self(), msg }

    receive do
      response -> response
    end
  end
end

defmodule Pawn do
  def new(), do: spawn(__MODULE__,:init, [] )
  def init(), do: loop({0,0})
  def loop({x, y} = state) do
    receive do
      {pid, {:goto, new_x, new_y}} -> 
        send pid, {new_x, new_y}
        {new_x, new_y}
      {pid, {:moveDelta, dx, dy}} -> 
        state = {x + dx, y + dy}
        send pid, state
        state
      {pid, :x} -> 
        send pid, x
        state
      {pid, :y} -> 
        send pid, y
        state
    end
    |> loop
  end
end

p1=Pawn.new()
Obj.call(p1,{:goto, 1, 2})
1=Obj.call(p1, :x)
2=Obj.call(p1, :y)
Obj.call(p1,{:moveDelta , 3, 1})
4=Obj.call(p1, :x ) 
3=Obj.call(p1 ,:y )
```

The code runs. Here is the output of the test cases you provided (after I fixed the syntax issues:

```
iex(5)> p1=Pawn.new()
#PID<0.350.0>
iex(6)> Obj.call(p1,{:goto, 1, 2})
{1, 2}
iex(7)> 1=Obj.call(p1, :x)
1
iex(8)> 2=Obj.call(p1, :y)
2
iex(9)> Obj.call(p1,{:moveDelta , 3, 1})
{4, 3}
iex(10)> 4=Obj.call(p1, :x )
4
iex(11)> 3=Obj.call(p1 ,:y )
3
iex(12)>
```

Also, I fixed syntax issues in the given problem.

Comment: Sir, thanks alot for your help. This really helped like 20 students

Comment: Did you get the other two handlers works? Did you get all the test cases working?